# Using gesture and mouse events together on AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, air, touch

I'm tring to develop an app on as3 for android. When i set to multitouch to gesture with

```
Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE;
```

command, i cant use any mouse event with one finger, altough my device support all touch event types.

```
trace("gesture support: "+ Multitouch.supportsGestureEvents +
      " touch support: " + Multitouch.supportsTouchEvents);

gesture support: true touch support: true
```

According to as3 class reference,i must handle touch events as mouse event, like in MultitouchInputMode.NONE. Also i cant use click events of buttons. Are there any parameter to set for using mouse events on gesture mode?

Comment: I believe gesture is the default inputMode, and it should work for mouseEvents as well as touchEvents.  No special setting should be needed.  Do you get mouseEvents with inputMode=none?

Answer (score 0):

In our app we used MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT and got mouse events normally, and implement the gestures by ourselves.